# How would I create a Text to Html parser?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, parsing

I want to know how does the stackoverflow parser works, and how to imitate it.
That is, `this` or *this* or **this** or [link](http://www.google.com).

I mean, it's pretty obvious but I would want a JavaScript `function` that turned this:

```
[Google](http://www.google.com)
*italic*
**bold**
`customStyle`
```

Into this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<span style="font-style:italic">italic</span>
<span style="font-weight:bold">italic</span>
<span class="custom">customStyle</span>
```

I was going to use regex but aside from them being somewhat complicated, after going through a couple of "parsing html" (not exactly what I was looking for) posts, like [The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) I got discouraged.

So, how should I go about making a parser?

Comment: That's _markdown_. You can use one of the available parsers instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: That's not really parsing, that's just replacing text with other text.

Comment: As @Vohuman noted, that is markdown, and as such you can just look up the code of any of the numerous markdown parsers to see how they work.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion, anyway I still don't know how to make one, or at least add rules over an existing one, can you help me with that? Thanks